# Npm Install Not working NPM already installed in system

Tags: node.js, npm

[image]

**NPM -v :- 4.0.5**

npm install command not working even node is installed. But, when i call npm -v worked fine..

Comment: Which error are you getting? We can't really answer a question if there is no info..

Comment: If you Want to use Multiple node or npm try to using  nvm (Node Version Management) or check file permission.This type of Problem Facing then change my file permission and work fine.

Comment: no error occur only processing...